# Proving UPGMA formula

Tags: algorithms

If A and B are two objects to get merged to object C by UPGMA(Unweighted Pair Group Method with Arithmetic Mean), then how can we prove that the distance between C and another object X defined by the UPGMA algorithm is calculated with

$$D(C,X)=\frac{|A|d(A,X)+|B|d(B,X)}{|A|+|B|}.$$

I was wondering if someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Beyond the fact that it is a barycentric formula with weights $|A|$ and $|B|$ ?

Comment: My aim is to show $D(C,X)=D(A\cup B, X)$, because I can prove that $$D(A\cup B ,X)=\frac{|A|d(A,X)+|B|d(B,X)}{|A|+|B|}.$$